# Jira: Limit assignee list to these users which are allowed to see the issue

Tags: jira

I try to configure my Jira system to work with different groups of users with different privileges. The restriction which user is able to access an issue is solved by configuring an issue level security. I let the assign-issue-privilege open to anyone because Jira cannot work with user groups out of the box. With this option anybody can assing an issue to other team members.

This combination makes some trouble because somebody can assign an issue to another user who cannot see this issue because of the issue level security. Does anybody know how the user pick list for the assignee can be limited to the users who are able to see the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve and limit different user privilege by creating Permission Scheme and restrict them to assign user.

You can create multiple groups and multiple permission schemes.
http://screencast.com/t/XWCMK9h2v

One group i.e. "TeamLeads" and their permission schemes "TeamLeadPermissions" and have permission to "assign users"

Another Group "TeamMember" and they have separate permission scheme "TeamMemberPermission" which doesnt have a permission.

Then you can assign both groups to the project.

So who has permission to assign user can view all the members of the project and other don't. Please mark as answer if it helps.